# sqlplus connection to 11g DB Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

i connected to sqlplus successfully but After close from terminal and back again ,occurs the following :

```
[soft3a6ala@soft3a6ala ~]$ su - oracle
Password: 
[oracle@soft3a6ala ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
bash: sqlplus: command not found...
```

How i can save this connect along time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing some environment variables.

```
ORACLE_HOME = {oracle_installation_path}
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $ORACLE_HOME\lib
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME\bin
```

You should put this into .profile for oracle user, so they get setted on oracle's user login.

For example, if Oracle is installed in `/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1`

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME\lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME\bin
```

The .profile file is located under the user home directory, in this case `/home/oracle`

If the file doesn't exist, yo can create it

```
touch .profile
```

and then edit an paste the values, setting ORACLE_HOME depending on your installation path.

save the file, and give it execution permissions

```
chmod +x .profile
```

Then logoff and login again, and you should be able to run it.

Also you can add the environment vars to `.bash_profile` which is also located on user home directory. If it doesn't exist, create it and do the same as with `.profile`

Comment: i founded the .bash_profile and open it like the following
 # .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi


# User specific environment and startup programs


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin 

export PATH

     ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $ORACLE_HOME\lib
     PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME\bin
     export ORACLE_HOME
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    export  PATH 
------------
but after log off and login again iface  this error
bash: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: command not found

Comment: Read my answer.. you must put the word `export` before every statement

Comment: i follow you exactly but i face this error :

-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1lib': not a valid identifier

Comment: Do not use ' for paths, also don't use spaces between `export VAR=value` (I put spaces on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH definition, I'll fix it now)

Comment: **before any words big thank for you about help you for me**
but After all this i still  facing same problem 

 bash: sqlplus: command not found...

Comment: try copying .bash_profile as .profile using `cp /home/oracle/.bash_profile /home/oracle/.profile` and then logoff and logon again.. Also update your post and paste your .profile contents please...

Comment: **thank you Eng  Cristian Meneses now every thing stable but now i face 
new isuue** :

SQL> connect hr / hr 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

Comment: This will be fixed if yuo add a new `export ORACLE_SID={your_sid}` to your `.profile / .bash_profile` files . If not sure what your Oracle SID is, check your ´tnsnames.ora´ file